# Search Whole Firebase Database For Single Value

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase auth ui in order to create users with mail and password but after the registration I forward them to a new activity in order to choose I username which needs to be unique. My idea was to search the whole DB in order to see if that username exists already or not. Here is how I am trying to do this but no luck till now:

```
submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("UserName", "Click: ");

                DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("USERS");
                mDatabase.orderByChild("username").equalTo("name1").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            //Here you can get all data
                            Log.d("UserName", "onDataChange: "+snapshot.toString());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

I have also tried this one:

```
submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("UserName", "Click: ");

                DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                Query query = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("USERS").orderByChild("username").equalTo("name1");

                ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            //TODO get the data here
                            Log.d("UserName", "onDataChange: " + dataSnapshot.toString());
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                };
                query.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);

            }
        });
```

[image: Database Preview]

Comment: .equalTo("name1") can you please confirm name1 is a string that you check or variable?

Comment: Its a String, I still have not added variable to check dynamically for a name.

Comment: try this String.valueOf(driverSnapshot.child("username").getValue()) in your DataSnapshot  for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason your code is not working is because "username" is not a direct child of the USERS table.
Your direct children will have random ids , which you can iterate trough with ChildEventListener like this:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("USERS");
mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
         User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class); // pojo
         if(user.getUsername().equals("name1") {
             // do something
         }

    }
    ...
)
```